# Parse jsonb field - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a field that is of type jsonb in a PostgreSQL database.
Example:

```
{"timestamp":"2016-12-14T04:15:04.836Z","receiptResult":{"status":"successful","timestamp":"2016-12-14T04:15:04.739Z","notes":"Customer Accepted"}}
```

How can I only return the "notes" in a select statement, I've tried:

```
SELECT data::json->>'notes' as notes
```

But nothing is returned, if I use:

```
SELECT data::json->'receiptResult' as notes;
```

It returns:

```
{"status":"successful","timestamp":"2016-114T04:15:04.739Z","notes":"Customer Accepted"}
```

But I only need the text after "notes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside key `receiptResult` has another JSON object, you cannot access it in top-level. Try this:

```
WITH sample AS (
    SELECT '{"timestamp":"2016-12-14T04:15:04.836Z","receiptResult":{"status":"successful","timestamp":"2016-12-14T04:15:04.739Z","notes":"Customer Accepted"}}'::jsonb AS my_column
)
SELECT my_column->'receiptResult'->>'notes' FROM sample;
```

As you can see, `->` operator returns value as a JSONB and `->>` operator returns as a text.

More info [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Michel, out of the office today, will test as soon as possible.

Comment: No problem. Regards!

Comment: Glad to help you @RuanLabuschagne